# css animation duration with dynamic elements

Tags: css, css-animations

I created a css animation for marquee effect.
I would like the animation speed to be in the same speed if i have 1 element in the marquee list or if i have 100 elements.

My css is:

```
.marquee {
    -webkit-animation-name: movement-smooth-up;
    animation-name: movement-smooth-up;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-duration: 10s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes movement-smooth-up {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20%);
            transform: translateY(20%);
    top: 0%;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
            transform: translateY(-100%);
    top: 100%;
  }
}
```

I've created a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z0nxchdd/1/)

As you can see when i have 10 elements the animation is fast, and when i have 2 elements the animation is slow.

How can i make sure both of them will be at the same speed?

Thank you!

Comment: You'll need to do some calculations, either server side or with Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're using 2 DIVs (two blocks) and the content has different size. To monitor the output of the elements at the same time, the CSS decreases the rate of 2 "TEXT's". Do a test, leave the same amount of "TEXT's" on both sides, which will run at the same speed, or change the arrangement of DIV's.

same speed:

```
<div class="marquee" style="float:left">
<div>TEXT</div>
<div>TEXT</div>
<div>TEXT</div>
<div>TEXT</div>
<div>TEXT</div>
<div>TEXT</div>
<div>TEXT</div>
<div>TEXT</div>
<div>TEXT</div>
<div>TEXT</div>
</div>

<div class="marquee" style="float:right">
<div>TEXT</div>
<div>TEXT</div>
<div>TEXT</div>
<div>TEXT</div>
<div>TEXT</div>
<div>TEXT</div>
<div>TEXT</div>
<div>TEXT</div>
<div>TEXT</div>
<div>TEXT</div>
</div>
```

OR

```
.marquee {
-webkit-animation-name: movement-smooth-up;
animation-name: movement-smooth-up;
-webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
animation-duration: 10s;

height:180px;

}
```

OR Change the height of the parent element.

```
html, body {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
.marquee {
-webkit-animation-name: movement-smooth-up;
animation-name: movement-smooth-up;
-webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
animation-duration: 10s;
height:100%;
}
```

[Example...](http://jsfiddle.net/z0nxchdd/2/)

Comment: I don't want to use a specific height cause my list is dynamic. Any other solutions maybe?

Comment: That will do it! Thank you